# Detecting drastic changes of values

Tags: r, math, statistics

I have  a time series and I want to find, if the values change drasticly. For example I have a  time series:

```
1,3,5,2,4,3,2,5,6,1,3,2,4,10,15,20,24,34,40
```

in this example where the value is 10, the time series begins to change drasticly. how can I detect such a change?

what I do is to compare the current value with the third past value, if the changes more than five, then there is a drastic change in the set, but I think there is not the best way.

Do you know may be a better way to do this job?

**EDIT**

I have a time series and I want to notice if the slope (in this image) begins to go fast up

[image]

Comment: I mean if there are some values in a set which are totaly difference from others. in my example most of values between 1 and 5 but from 10 it begins to increase on 15-20-24-34-40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ts <- c(1,3,5,2,4,3,2,5,6,1,3,2,4,10,15,20,24,34,40)
#shows elements where difference between x and x + lagth element is greater than 10 
diffts <- diff(ts)

rollingwindow <- 5

# option 1
avgslope1 <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = (length(ts)-rollingwindow))
for ( i in 1 : (length(ts)-rollingwindow))
{
  avgslope1[i] <- round(mean(ts[i:(i+rollingwindow)]),2)
}


#option 2
avgslope2 <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = (length(ts)-rollingwindow))
for ( i in 1 : (length(diffts)-rollingwindow))
{
  avgslope2[i] <- round(mean(diffts[i:(i+rollingwindow)]),2)
}
```

`avgslope1` is rolling average of 5 values. If you run `ts[1 + which.max(diff(avgslope1))]`, you will get the value from which the average value of the next five values changes steepest. Similarly `ts[1 + which.max(diff(avgslope2))]` returns the element from which the average change in value is the highest over the next 5 elements.

```
> avgslope1
 [1]  3.00  3.17  3.50  3.67  3.50  3.33  3.17  3.50  4.33  5.83  9.00 12.50 17.83 23.83
> avgslope2
 [1]  0.17  0.33  0.17 -0.17 -0.17 -0.17  0.33  0.83  1.50  3.17  3.50  5.33  6.00  0.00
> ts
 [1]  1  3  5  2  4  3  2  5  6  1  3  2  4 10 15 20 24 34 40
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. actually the length of my time series is relative. after each second a value is added to the series and I don't know, what is the value. I only one to detect big change in the series

Comment: You need to be more specific about "big change". You could just atke the largest value from the `avgslope ` vector, for instance which would mean the steepest increase over 5 continues values.

Comment: could you please explain me a little bit more? If I take the largest value from avgslop, how can I notice that a value or a set of value are difference from the others. In my example `10-15-20--24-34-40` are difference from `1-3-5-2-4-2-5-6-1-3-2-4`

Comment: Edited answer. But you really need to define 'difference/big change' better.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer,  I have tested your idea and I think it is my answer, if I have another range of value in my time series like `10-15-20--24-34-40` then the result of rolling average is more than one, but IF I have only a range like `1-3-5-2-4-2-5-6-1-3-2-4` the rolling average is always smaller than 1. I have edited my post too

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking a question?

Comment: Erm... sorry, but I don't understand what you said. In the example you've posted, you should get a value somewhere around the 90th element or so but trying `ts[1 + which.max(diff(avgslope2))]` or `ts[1 + which.max(diff(avgslope1))]`.